# In-depth derivation of implied volatility in the SABR model

Tags: implied-volatility, sabr, derivation

I'm working through the derivation of Hagan's formula (Hagan et al, 2002) for the implied volatility of an option in the SABR model. I'm finding it pretty confusing. Most of my hang-ups are coming from the singular perturbation expansion. Specifically, how does one use singular perturbation expansion to find the solution of,
$$
P_\tau = \frac{1}{2}\varepsilon^2\alpha^2C^2(f)P_{ff} + \varepsilon^2\rho\nu\alpha^2C(f)P_{f\alpha} + \frac{1}{2}\varepsilon^2\nu^2\alpha^2P_{\alpha\alpha}
$$
to be,
$$
P = \frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{2\pi\varepsilon^2C^2(K) \tau }} e^{-\frac{(f-K)^2}{2\varepsilon^2\alpha^2C^2(K)\tau}}\{1+...\}.
$$
If anyone has any resources/textbooks that they think might help that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi, I have found a paper, but far from being able to shed light on the matter. It's pretty scary, it uses Riemannian manifolds and tensor calculus, I think you have to be at least an Einstein to read it. But maybe looking in the bibliography at the end you can find something. https://d-nb.info/104960718X/34

Comment: @AlexisSánchezTello That looks awesome, thanks! A bit above my pay grade but it’s a great starting point for further research.